# New Relic Flutter Integration

Tags: flutter, newrelic

We’re converting our current Android and iOS codebase to a single Flutter code base. How can we do this with Flutter's NewRelic?

Comment: Have you got any further? facing the same problem here

Comment: hello, yes I did. I created a plugin for that and could get a custom event. But that is all. I highly recommend don't spend your time creating a custom agent because New Relic Plugin does not have the capability to monitor API requests automatically from a flutter application, as a new relic agent can only track NSURLConnection, NSURLSession for iOS and HttpURLConnection, OkHttp2 for Android. NewRelic agent provided API to track custom network requests generated. iOS custom network tracking API requires the NRTimer instance to log response time information.

Comment: Also, Creating an NRTimer instance and passing that instance over the method channel is not possible.